# Does PCA helps to include all the variables even if there is high collinearity among variables?

Tags: linear-regression, pca, collinearity

I have a dataset that has high collinearity among variables. When I created the linear regression model, I could not include more than five variables ( I eliminated the feature whenever VIF>5). But I need to have all the variables in the model and find their relative importance. Is there any way around it?. I was thinking about doing PCA and creating models on principal components. Does it help?.

Comment: Why can’t you include more than five variables?

Comment: Because VIF increases beyond 5 when I use more than 5 features.

Comment: So VIF exceeds $5$…how does that impact your analysis?

Comment: Doesn't it mean high collinearity in the data? So that I can't keep those features

Comment: But VIF of 4.5 also means that there is (multi)collinearity. How does VIF $>5$ impact your analysis?

Comment: I set the threshold as 5. Isn't VIF 3-5 usually specified as the threshold.

Comment: Why have a threshold at all?

Comment: What are you suggesting? I'm not very clear

Comment: Why not just include all of your variables? Why set a cutoff based on VIF?

Comment: Wouldn't that make coefficients unstable if multicollinearity exists?. I intend to get feature importance from the model. What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest you be very clear about your goals. // Yes, multicollinearity can result in coefficient instability (variance), but omitting variables can result in bias. Are you familiar with the bias variance decomposition of mean squared error? // Figuring out which five (or four, or six) variables you will include in your model can invalidate downstream results. This is at least evocative of the [myriad issues with stepwise regression](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/). (The math does not depend on Stata software.)

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I need to read up on this. But I'm still unclear about the way around this problem. How do I find the feature importance if I have high collinearity in the data?. Is it possible to find feature importance in a meaningful way in this data?

Comment: It is a hard problem to untangle feature influence when the features are related. The gist is that, when the features are related, how can you attribute changes in $y$ to either of the features instead of the other?

Comment: A [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555145/ridge-regression-for-multicollinearity-and-outliers/555163#555163) of mine on the statistics Stack, Cross Validated, is worth a read. Correlated features get An undeserved bad wrap.

Answer (score 1):

When using [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en), you should not try to interpret the single features anymore. The [principal components](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) are multiple linear combinations of your variables that should not be related to the original features.

When you want to work on feature importance, you can use [random forests](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/random-forests) or [decision trees](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/decision-trees) instead, as described before. You can do it with [neural networks](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/artificial-neural-networks) as well by randomizing or shuffling one feature, re-train the network, and comparing the performance.

Answer (score -1):

[PCA](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/94614/71442) will generate „new“ (transformed) features which are orthogonal (non-correlated). However, since the original features are transformed, you can hardly claim to say a lot about the importance of (original) features based on PCA.

One obvious alternative would be to use a random forest (RF) to determine [feature importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html). Using tree based models (like RF or tree based boosting) you do not need to care about collinearity in the feature space.

Comment: But my principal components are still a linear combination of the original variables, right?. Can I distribute the feature importance of the principal components to the original variables somehow?

Comment: Not sure about this. Tend to say it is not a good idea…